# Compile Time Constant in if condition in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is the edited one .I am getting an error that **k is not a constant** .  **pa** is the  module that should be called with respect to the **ith bit of k**. k is an input to the module. **pd** module should be done for all **i bits of k**. This is a cryptographic algorithm. The problem here is with the code I have written. How can I make it synthesizable? Can k not be an input parameter? Thank you @qiu for the previous edits.

```
module pm(
  input [6:0] Ux,
  input [6:0] Uy,
  input [6:0] Uz,
  input [9:0] k,
  input       clk,
  input       reset,
  output reg [6:0] Wx,
  output reg [6:0] Wy,
  output reg [6:0] Wz   );

  wire [6:0] a1x,a1y,a1z,a2x,a2y,a2z; 

  always @ (Ux,Uy,Uz)
  begin
   assign Wx=Ux;
   assign Wy=Uy;
   assign Wz=Uz;
  end

  genvar i;
  generate 
  for(i=9;i>=0;i=i-1) begin : L1
    pd d0(.Xp(Wx),.Yp(Wy),.Zp(Wz),.Xb(a1x),.Yb(a1y),Zb(a1z),.clk(clk),.reset(reset));
    always @(a1x,a1y,a1z)
    begin
     Wx <= a1x;
     Wy <= a1y;
     Wz <= a1z;
    end
    if ( k[i] )
    begin
      pa a0(.Xp(Ux),.Yp(Uy),.Zp(Uz),.Xq(Wx),.Yq(Wy),.Zq(Wz),.Xr(a2x),.Yr(a2y),.Zr(a2z),.clk(clk),.reset(reset));
      always @(a2x,a2y,a2z)
      begin
       Wx <= a2x;
       Wy <= a2y;
       Wz <= a2z;
      end
    end
  end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ( k[i] == 1)` has no meaning inside the genvar

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @meir this would have been better as a comment, or adding more content or explanation.

Comment: @gung Sorry that i didn't explain the thing properly. I will edit and explain.

Answer (score 0):

All non-blocking assignments should be in an always/initial block:

```
Wx <= a1x;
Wy <= a1y;
Wz <= a1z;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more common to have registers/ports written as [6:0] instead of [0:6].

Inputs can not be `reg`.

Assuming your not stuck with Verilog-95 port lists do not have to be written out twice:

```
module pm(Ux,Uy,Uz,k,Wx,Wy,Wz,clk,reset);
  input [0:6] Ux,Uy,Uz;
  input reg[0:9] k;
  input clk,reset;
  output [0:6] Wx,Wy,Wz;
```

Can be come:

```
module pm(
  input  [6:0] Ux,
  input  [6:0] Uy,
  input  [6:0] Uz,
  input  [9:0] k,
  input        clk,
  input        reset,
  output [6:0] Wx
  output [6:0] Wy,
  output [6:0] Wz
);
```

When writing verilog RTL we can imply combinatorial logic `always @*` or `assign`. Imply flip-flops `always @(posedge clk ...` or instantiate modules.

You have many statements of the form `Wx <= a1x;` which do not fit into the above, they need to be contained by an `always` which defines its behaviour.

Verilog describes hardware, real physical electonics, **K is an input**  which implies that the following section:

```
 if ( k[i] == 1 ) begin
  pa a0(.Xp(Ux),.Yp(Uy),.Zp(Uz),.Xq(Wx),.Yq(Wy),.Zq(Wz),.Xr(a2x),.Yr(a2y),.Zr(a2z),.clk(clk),.reset(reset));
```

Would create and destroy hardware on the fly, this is not possible. If statements can be used like this but the conditional must be a compile time constant.

Generate loops are an advanced topic for Verilog, it would be best to avoid using them until your more comfortable with the basics of the language.

Comment: Thank you @Morgan. The answer is really helpful. I have a doubt that how can I use a conditional statement in verilog? Also will you please elaborate about the compile time constant?